# How to update R data.frame column values efficiently?

Tags: r

Say I have this table A

```
                mpg 
RX4            21.0  
Wag            21.0  
Datsun         22.8  
Drive          21.4   
Sportabout     18.7   
Valiant        18.1  
Duste          14.3   
Merc           24.4
```

Now I have a table B

```
              mpg
RX4           60.0  
Wag           60.0  
Datsun        70.8
```

What I want to do is to update the mpg value of Table A according to Table B, I can do that easily using hashmap in Java, may I know what is the efficient way of doing that in R?

Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: If you can rely on row.names of your data.frame's (i.e. 'Mazda RX4' etc..) you can do `df1[row.names(df2),'mpg'] <- df2$mpg`

Comment: row names are all you've got to go on here!

Comment: @digEmAll You should post this as an answer.  I deleted my post.

Comment: @Akrun: actually you've posted a nearly identical solution before my comment (I also think your code is equally efficient, since I suspect when you subset a data.frame using row names it uses match function under the hood). Please, undelete your answer and feel free to add my solution as an addendum to yours ;)

Comment: Thanks very much indeed for the help of akrun and digEmAil. One of my minor question is, if df2 is not all in df1, will that also works? Say df2 have 3 cars same with df1(mtcars), and df2 has 2 additional new model not in df1 and need to be added in df1 if not exist in df1 before. Thanks very mcuh.

Comment: @WinWiseWill do you mean efficient in terms of programmer time/ease or in terms of execution on many thousands of observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `match` to match the rownames of `df1` (first dataset) and `df2` (second) and then use it as a index to replace values of `mpg` in `df1` with those from `df2`

```
 indx <- match(row.names(df2), row.names(df1))
 df1$mpg[indx] <- df2$mpg[indx]
```

Or you could use the `compact` solution offered by @digEmAll

```
 df1[row.names(df2),'mpg'] <- df2$mpg
```

#### Update

Using the new info about some elements in `df2` are not in `df1` and wants to add those rows into `df1:

```
 indx <- match(row.names(df2), row.names(df1))
 indx1 <- indx[!is.na(indx)]

 indx2 <- match(row.names(df1), row.names(df2))
 indx22 <- indx2[!is.na(indx2)]

 df1$mpg[indx1] <- df2$mpg[indx22]
 df1N <- rbind(df1,df2[setdiff(rownames(df2), rownames(df1)),,drop=FALSE])
 df1N
 #           mpg
 #RX4        60.0
 #Wag        60.0
 #Datsun     70.8
 #Drive      21.4
 #Sportabout 18.7
 #Valiant    18.1
 #Duste      14.3
 #Merc       24.4
 #Mazda      45.0
 #Mercury    42.0
```

Or you could use `intersect` and `setdiff`

```
  indxN <- intersect(row.names(df1), row.names(df2))
  df1[indxN, 'mpg']  <- df2[indxN, 'mpg']
  rbind(df1,df2[setdiff(rownames(df2), rownames(df1)),,drop=FALSE])
```

#### new data

```
  df1 <- structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 
   24.4)), .Names = "mpg", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("RX4", 
  "Wag", "Datsun", "Drive", "Sportabout", "Valiant", "Duste", "Merc"
  ))


  df2 <- structure(list(mpg = c(45, 60, 60, 42, 70.8)), .Names = "mpg",
   class =    "data.frame", row.names = c("Mazda", "RX4", "Wag",
  "Mercury", "Datsun"))
```

#### old data

```
  df1 <- structure(list(mpg = c(60, 70, 80.8, 90.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 
  24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8), cyl = c(6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 
  4L, 4L, 6L, 6L), disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225, 360, 
 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167.6), hp = c(110L, 110L, 93L, 110L, 175L, 
 105L, 245L, 62L, 95L, 123L, 123L), drat = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 
 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 
 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 3.15, 3.44, 3.44), qsec = c(16.46, 
 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20, 22.9, 18.3, 18.9
 ), vs = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), am = c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gear = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), carb = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", 
 "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
 "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", 
 "Valiant", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", 
 "Merc 280C"), class = "data.frame")

 df2 <- structure(list(mpg = c(60, 70, 80.8, 90.4), cyl = c(6L, 6L, 4L, 
 6L), disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258), hp = c(110L, 110L, 93L, 110L
 ), drat = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 
 3.215), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44), vs = c(0L, 0L, 
 1L, 1L), am = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), gear = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), carb = c(4L, 
 4L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", 
 "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
 c("Mazda RX4","Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive"))
```

Comment: matching is unnecessary since you can index on row names, see @digEmAll's comment

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, I did saw that, but I posted this before his comment.  I can delete this.

Comment: @akrun: reading the subsetting methods documentation of data.frame, it seems that the difference between the two methods is that the compact version performs a partial matching on the row.names. e.g. `df1['Val',]` is the same as `df1['Valiant',]`.

Answer (score 1):

@akrun solution works but is heavy where you can use `data.table` package with a few neat lines of code:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE)
dt2 = data.table(df2, keep.rownames=TRUE)
setkey(dt1, rn)
dt1[dt2, `:=`(mpg = i.mpg)]
```

Where df1 and df2 are:

```
df1 = structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4)), .Names = "mpg", class= "data.frame", row.names = c("RX4", "Wag", "Datsun", "Drive", "Sportabout", "Valiant", "Duste","Merc"))

df2 = structure(list(mpg = c(45, 60, 60, 42, 70.8)), .Names = "mpg",class ="data.frame", row.names = c("Mazda", "RX4", "Wag","Mercury", "Datsun"))
```

Comment: thanks very much indeed for your help. But I don't understand the meaning of dt1[dt2, `:=`(mpg = i.mpg)], can you explain a little bit on the `:=`. Thanks very much.